# RequestScoped bean destroyed in confirmDialog

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have RequestScoped bean because I'm redirecting the user from dataTable with records to edit page. In this dataTable I have delete buttons:

```
<p:column>
    <p:commandButton update=":deleteNewsDialog" oncomplete="deleteNewsDlg.show()" icon="ui-icon-closethick">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{news}" target="#{newsBean.news}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

And here is the dialog:

```
<p:confirmDialog id="deleteNewsDialog" message="Czy na pewno chcesz usunąć wiadomość o tytule &quot;#{newsBean.news.title}&quot;?"
    header="Usuwanie wiadomości" severity="alert"
    widgetVar="deleteNewsDlg" appendToBody="true">
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="Usuń" actionListener="#{newsBean.delete}" update=":newsesTableForm:newsesTable, :newsesTableForm:newsGrowl"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Anuluj" oncomplete="deleteNewsDlg.hide();"/>
    </h:form>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

When newsBean.delete is fired, newsBean not longer exists so I get a lot of ugly validation exceptions. I have other pages like this with ViewScoped beans and there it is working like a charm. Help?

Comment: newsBean will exist but it will be a fresh instance. Please show error log and implementation of newsBean.delete.

Comment: Thats the point! How to maintain the old instance instead of getting new one? Error log will be useless at this point, it's just bunch of validation exceptions due to null news property. The delete method is just calling entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(news)), not directly of course.

Comment: Change your bean to ViewScope

Comment: Not an option cuz I need it on edit page redirected from the page with dataTable.

Comment: Just now I realized my edit doesn't work either :D. I think I have to stick with SessionScoped in that case. Or maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A request scoped bean has a lifetime of exactly one HTTP request/response. So retrieving the entire view with the form is already one HTTP request/response. The request scoped bean is trashed by end of the response. When you fire an ajax request on the view, then you're essentially sending a new HTTP request. This will thus create a new request scoped bean which get trashed by end of HTTP response. So every ajax request on the same view get its own request scoped bean instance.

This is not what you want if you need to maintain data related to the view. You need to put the bean in the view scope instead. The bean will live as long as you're interacting with the same view by ajax and return `null` or `void` in action listener methods. Note that when you return a `String`, even if empty, the view will be recreated and thus the view scoped bean will be trashed.

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)