# Double p:selectOneMenu to feed one last p:selectOneMenu with p:ajax listener

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have 3 `<p:selectOneMenu>`, two of them are here to feed the 3rd. But when I select in one combobox, the value disappears in the other one.

For doing this, I'm using 2 `<p:ajax>` components into the two first `<p:selectonemenu>`.

```
<p:panel columns="4" cellpadding="5" id="panelAddColor" header="#{msg['configuration_assignment_modif_panelheader']}" style="width: 500px;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h:outputLabel for="comboBox_listBump" value="#{msg['bumper']}" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <p:selectOneMenu   id="comboBox_listBump" value="#{assignmentModificationController.idTypeBumper}" effect="fade" style="width: 100px;" styleClass="greyBackMenu" panelStyleClass="greyBackPanel">
                    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{assignmentModificationController.comboboxBumpersChange()}" update="machine,comboBox_listBump,tint" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['menu_production_NewTech']}" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{assignmentModificationController.listBumper}" var="b" itemLabel="#{b.name}" itemValue="#{b.id}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p:message for="comboBox_listBump" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h:outputLabel for="tint" value="#{msg['configuration_safetystock_tint']}" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="tint" value="#{assignmentModificationController.idTint}" effect="fade" styleClass="greyBackMenu" panelStyleClass="greyBackPanel">
                    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{assignmentModificationController.comboboxBumpersChangeTint()}" update="machine,comboBox_listBump,tint" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['menu_production_NewTech']}" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{assignmentModificationController.listTypeTint}" var="p" itemLabel="#{p.name}&#160;&#160;" itemValue="#{p.id}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h:outputLabel for="machine" value="#{msg['menu_configuration_machines']}" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="machine" value="#{assignmentModificationController.idMachine}" effect="fade" >
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['menu_production_NewTech']}" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{assignmentModificationController.listMachines}" var="p" itemLabel="#{p.name}&#160;&#160;" itemValue="#{p.id}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p:message for="machine" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <center>
        <p:commandButton value="Créer" update="growl,panelAddColor" validateClient="true" style="font-size: 13px;" action="#{assignmentModificationController.addTintAssignment}" />
        -
        <p:commandButton value="Quitter" style="font-size: 13px;" action="TO_config_menu" />
    </center>
</p:panel>
```

And my test in bean :

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    setListBumper(TypeBumpHome.getAll());
    setListTint(TypeTintHome.getAll());
    setListMachines(MachineHome.getAll());

    List<TypeTint> allTypeTint = new ArrayList<TypeTint>();
    allTypeTint = TypeTintHome.getAll();

    for (TypeTint t : allTypeTint) {
        colorList.put(t.getId(), t.getName());
    }
    setListTypeTint(TypeTintHome.getAll());
}

public void comboboxBumpersChange() {
    System.out.println("BUMPER : " + getIdTypeBumper() + " " + getIdTint());
}

public void comboboxBumpersChangeTint() {
    System.out.println("TINT : " + getIdTypeBumper() + " " + getIdTint());
}
```

Comment: Which scope are you using for the bean? Is the second menu dependent from the first one too?

Comment: Hello ! @RequestScoped, no there is no dependancy between the 1st and the 2nd. But the 3rd is build with the 1st and the 2nd (dependancy).

Comment: Being it `@RequestScoped` you're rebuilding the bean for each request (setting the default values when an ajax request happens). Try to go with `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: It works ! Thank you, I was thinking I ever try this with @SessionScoped ... You can post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, you're using a `@RequestScoped` bean. The ajax events cause a new request, so it's being rebuilt and consequently loosing its current state. The solution is to use the view scope and take advantage of the JSF' stateful nature.

**See also**

- [Difference between View and Request scope in managed beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025998/difference-between-view-and-request-scope-in-managed-beans)
- [Request Scope vs View Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10464471/1199132)
- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)